# If no post or less than 3, Then add an other tag name to the query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to make a section displaying `post` within a product page on **wordpress**. This post list would be displaying all posts according to `tag names` and following an `order of priority`.

Each of my products got 3 tags value which are.

```
$variant

$model

$brand
```

All the post which got the tag $variant should displayed first

```
If no post ( with 'tag' => $variant ) OR the total of post < 6

Then get the rest of the post ( with 'tag' => $model )

If no post ( with 'tag' => $model ) OR the total of post < 6

Then get the rest of the post ( with 'tag' => $brand )
```

I tried multiple solutions so far, like merging queries or trying to change queries when no more post. But didn't seemed to make it work. So i am back on my first code right now trying to order the post by the tag value i want to display first.

```
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$args=array('posts_per_page'=>6, 'tag' => "'.$variant.', '.$model.', '.$brand.'");
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) : the_post();
       get_template_part( 'template-parts/molecule/card', 'vertical' );
   endwhile;
endif;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Any idea if this is possible ?

Comment: It is possible, but you need to show us some code so we can help. What have you got so far?

Comment: @cabrerahector Yes. i don't know if it would help cause i got back to my first code, but here it is.

Comment: There are a couple issues here: first, the `tag` parameter needs to be an array, not strings. You do not need to set the `$wp_query` to `null` just use `wp_reset_query()`. And don't use `$wp_query` as your variable, use something like `$card_query = new WP_Query( $args )`;

Comment: The `tag` parameter also accepts a comma separated string of tag slugs, disinfor. Check the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters), under **Show Posts From Several Tags**.

Comment: @cabrerahector well I'll be! Thanks for sharing that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'tag' => $variant
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Let's check how many posts with the variant tag we find
$count = 0;

// Posts by variant have been found, display them
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) { the_post();
        $count++;
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/molecule/card', 'vertical' );
    }
}

// We don't have 6 posts yet, let's get more posts by model and/or brand
if ( $count < 6 ) {

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 6 - $count,
        'tag' => $model
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Posts by model have been found, display them
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while( have_posts() ) { the_post();
            $count++;
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/molecule/card', 'vertical' );
        }
    }

    // We still don't have 6 posts, let's add some more posts by brand
    if ( $count < 6 ) {

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 6 - $count,
            'tag' => $brand
        );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // Posts by model have been found, display them
        if ( have_posts() ) {
            while( have_posts() ) { the_post();
                $count++;
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/molecule/card', 'vertical' );
            }
        }

    }

}

$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

For clarity though, I'd rewrite the code to this to avoid having to mess with the original `$wp_query` object and for readability:

```
$posts_per_page = 6;
$count = 0;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'tag' => $variant
);
$posts_by_variant = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $posts_by_variant->have_posts() ) {
    while( $posts_by_variant->have_posts() ) { $posts_by_variant->the_post();
        $count++;
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/molecule/card', 'vertical' );
    }
}

// We don't have 6 posts, let's get more posts by model and/or brand
if ( $count < $posts_per_page ) {

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page - $count,
        'tag' => $model
    );
    $posts_by_model = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Posts by model have been found, display them
    if ( $posts_by_model->have_posts() ) {
        while( $posts_by_model->have_posts() ) { $posts_by_model->the_post();
            $count++;
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/molecule/card', 'vertical' );
        }
    }

    // We still don't have 6 posts, let's add some more posts by brand
    if ( $count < $posts_per_page ) {

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page - $count,
            'tag' => $brand
        );
        $posts_by_brand = new WP_Query( $args );

        // Posts by model have been found, display them
        if ( $posts_by_brand->have_posts() ) {
            while( $posts_by_brand->have_posts() ) { $posts_by_brand->the_post();
                $count++;
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/molecule/card', 'vertical' );
            }
        }

    }

}

// Reset original post object
wp_reset_postdata();
```